# Javascript: point-free style in callback

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, this, pointfree

So I wanted the elements of the array `arr1` that also happen to belong to the array `arr2`. I figured `arr1.filter(arr2.includes)` should do the trick, but it gave me an error (see below). Strangely, though, `arr1.filter(x => arr2.incudes(x))` worked fine. Even though the functions `arr2.includes` and `x => arr2.includes(x)` aren't referentially equal, shouldn't they take the same values on the same inputs? What am I missing, here?

```
> arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
> arr2 = ['a', 'c', 'd']
[ 'a', 'c', 'd' ]
>
> arr1.filter(x => arr2.includes(x))
[ 'a', 'c' ]
> arr1.filter(arr2.includes)
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at includes (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at repl:1:6
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons you can't just do `arr1.filter(arr2.includes)`:

1. `arr2.includes` is just a reference to the function, but what you need is both a reference to the function *and* to the array that you want to use it on (`arr2`). You could solve that by using `Function.prototype.bind`, but:
2. `filter` passes its callback multiple arguments, not just one: It passes the value, its index, and the original array. `includes` will try to use the second argument it receives as the index at which to start searching, so when `filter` passes it the index, it'll use that and skip leading entries.

So the usual solution is to use a wrapper function that knows it needs to use `includes` on `arr2` and knows to only pass it the one argument — which is what you've done with your arrow function.

But see also [Michał Perłakowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504655/157247) for an answer from the functional programming perspective using a utility function to create the callback function rather than creating it inline.

Comment: It is worth noting that a lookup via `Array.prototype.includes` is rather slow. For a set operation like the intersection of two arrays `Set` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could implement an `includes` function that could be used in point-free style:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'c', 'd'];
const includes = arr => x => arr.includes(x);
console.log(arr1.filter(includes(arr2)));
```

If you're interested in functional programming in JavaScript, you should try the [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) library. With Ramda your code could look like this:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'c', 'd'];
// First option: R.flip
console.log(R.filter(R.flip(R.contains)(arr1), arr2));
// Second option: R.__ (placeholder argument)
console.log(R.filter(R.contains(R.__, arr1), arr2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yup, good alternative if you prefer to use a utility function for this.